# Running nginx as reverse Proxy behind a corporate Proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

i am trying to run a nginx reverse Proxy behind a corporate Proxy. The corporate proxy is running on

```
http://someproxy.company.com:3128
```

for both - http and https connections.

My nginx config in the http module looks like this:

```
upstream subdomain.external.com {
    server someproxy.company.com:3128;
    }
```

and in the server module like this:

```
server {
        
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  reverse.company.com;
        
        ssl_certificate      mycert.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key  mykey.key;
        
        ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        
    location /target {
        proxy_pass http://subdomain.external.com/target;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
```

You can see, the reverse proxy_pass target is a http target. This works as expected over the corporate proxy.

Now to my problem: The proxy_pass target should be on https! But if i switch the proxy_pass target to https://subdomain.external.com/target, nginx is trying to connect to the upstream on https. This results in Error Log Entries:

```
[error] 6524#6288: *1 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: CLIENT_IP_HERE, server: reverse.company.com, request: "GET /activation HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://someproxy.company.com:3128/target", host: "reverse.company.com"
```

As i mentioned on top, our Proxy Address is http://someproxy.company.com:3128 for both, http and https requests.

Is there a way to tell nginx to use the Upstream on http even the proxy_pass target is on https?

I tried these parameters on the location /target without success:

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO http;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_ssl_verify off;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the location /taget the parameter

```
proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
```

has to be set.